# Concatenated Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concatenation

I'm trying to execute this select:

```
 SELECT a.*,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente

 FROM pedidos  a with(nolock), 
    pedidos_status b with(nolock), 
     cadastro c with(nolock)  

 WHERE  a.status <> '' and 
  a.status=b.status and 
   a.id_doc = c.id_doc 
    and c.nome like 'CAR%'
     and data_inclusao BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160202'
```

With this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE LISTA_PEDIDOS
@Sdatainicio varchar(100),
@Sdatafim varchar(100),
@chaveBusca varchar(100),
@TipoBusca varchar(100) 

AS 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000) = ''

SET @SQL += 'SELECT a.*,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente '

SET @SQL += ' FROM pedidos   a with(nolock), '
SET @SQL += ' pedidos_status b with(nolock), '
SET @SQL += ' cadastro c with(nolock) '

SET @SQL += ' WHERE '
SET @SQL += ' a.status <> '''' and '
SET @SQL += ' a.status=b.status and '
SET @SQL += ' a.id_doc = c.id_doc '



IF isnull(@chaveBusca,'')<>''
 BEGIN

     IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO'
        SET @SQL += ' and a.numped= '''+@chaveBusca+''''

     IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'CLIENTE'
        SET @SQL += ' and c.nome like '''+@chaveBusca+'%'''
 END

IF not (isnull(@chavebusca,'')<>'' and isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO')
    SET @SQL += ' and data_inclusao BETWEEN '''+@Sdatainicio+''' AND '''+@Sdatafim+''''

EXECUTE @SQL
```

and this command:

```
exec LISTA_PEDIDOS '20160101','20160202','CAR','CLIENTE'
```

but it gives me this error message:

Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure LISTA_PEDIDOS, Line 39

The name 'SELECT a.*,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente  FROM pedidos   a with(nolock),  pedidos_status b with(nolock),  cadastro c with(nolock)  WHERE  a.status <> '' and  a.status=b.status and  a.id_doc = c.id_doc  and c.nome like 'CAR%' and data_inclusao BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160202'' is not a valid identifier.

Is it because im using EXECUTE @SQL at the end of the procedure? Im new at this btw.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is `EXECUTE(@SQL)` which executes the string in @SQL.  What you are doing is variable procedure execution: `EXECUTE @SQL` which tries to execute a stored procedure whose name is in the @SQL variable

Comment: oh... thanks very much... it worked perfectly...

Comment: How screwed would you be if this was called with a parameters of: `@TipoBusco='PEDIDO', @chaveBusca=''; drop table pedidos;--`? Check out `sp_executesql`.

Comment: I dont know what you mean.

Comment: Why you are using dynamic sql here in the first place? What you have here is vulnerable to sql injection. You should just use a parameterized query here and forget the dynamic sql. You also have the old ANSI-89 style join syntax. You should update that. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And you really should read this before you continue littering your database with nolock hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And my last suggestion is to use meaningful aliases instead of a, b, c

Comment: Thats the way I'm being taught. But thanks for the hints, I'll surely read more about this and learn the better way so I improve myself, since I'm new at this and have no habits yet.